# How to convert a polygon into a set of points within its border using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo

I need to convert a polygon into a set of points in MapInfo with a specific inter distance, I can't insert them manually as I need to have a large number of points (up to 10,000) at each run.

Comment: Do you want to create a set of points with a specific spacing using a polygon boundary (like a "fishnet" without the lines) or convert the vertices of a polygon into point features after generalizing the polygon? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to use MapBasic and do some coding. The steps you need are probably:

1. Create a new table to store your points
2. Query your existing polygon, and find out if it is a multipolygon, and if so which particular number of the polygons in the set you are interested in
3. Store the object as a variable
4. Cycle through all the nodes of your polygon, finding the co-ordinates, using
   `ObjectNodeX(object,  polygon_num , node_num)`
   and 
   `ObjectNodeY(object,  polygon_num , node_num)`

   *object* is the object you are working with, *polygon_num* is the number of the polygon   and *node_num* is the order of the node.
5. Work out the length of each vertex.
6. Work out how many points you need on each vertex, and where they should be
7. Insert your new points into the new table

   `Insert Into NewTable(Obj)`

   `Values (CreatePoint(x, y))`